# Double comment on network lag

Tags: bug, comments

I've seen my comments double post occasionally when my network connection is poor. I'm not sure the cause and I have never had the developer console logging/open when it occurs. I am certain I've only clicked the `post` button once though.

Here's a thread where it most recently occurred for me: [Joining a table in mysqli and then fetch the matched result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630422/joining-a-table-in-mysqli-and-then-fetch-the-matched-result)

In case one of the dups is deleted the ids were:

1. [comment76246508_44630422](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630422/joining-a-table-in-mysqli-and-then-fetch-the-matched-result#comment76246508_44630422)
2. [comment76246518_44630422](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630422/joining-a-table-in-mysqli-and-then-fetch-the-matched-result#comment76246518_44630422)

   **Newer dup**
3. [comment76484634_44751751](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751751/how-to-get-a-query-in-mysql-that-tells-wich-registry-is-getting-higher-values-in#comment76484634_44751751)
4. [comment76484636_44751751](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751751/how-to-get-a-query-in-mysql-that-tells-wich-registry-is-getting-higher-values-in#comment76484636_44751751)
5. [comment76705975_44862710](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862710/php-sql-update-single-colum-password?noredirect=1#comment76705975_44862710)
6. [comment76705969_44862710](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862710/php-sql-update-single-colum-password?noredirect=1#comment76705969_44862710)
7. [comment77499670_45268361](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268361/page-is-not-working-with-php-require-when-enquiring-mysql-db-for-image-file-loca#comment77499670_45268361)
8. [comment77499675_45268361](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268361/page-is-not-working-with-php-require-when-enquiring-mysql-db-for-image-file-loca#comment77499675_45268361)
9. [comment77499688_45268361](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268361/page-is-not-working-with-php-require-when-enquiring-mysql-db-for-image-file-loca#comment77499688_45268361)
10. [comment77499689_45268361](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268361/page-is-not-working-with-php-require-when-enquiring-mysql-db-for-image-file-loca#comment77499689_45268361)
11. [comment77741738_45390343](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390343/mysqli-num-rows-is-not-working#comment77741738_45390343)
12. [comment77741734_45390343](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390343/mysqli-num-rows-is-not-working#comment77741734_45390343)
13. [comment77741876_45390596](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390596/my-php-mysql-script-is-working-perfectly-fine-locally-but-not-on-my-live-site#comment77741876_45390596)
14. [comment77741869_45390596](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390596/my-php-mysql-script-is-working-perfectly-fine-locally-but-not-on-my-live-site#comment77741869_45390596)

[image: screenshot]

I caught it with the developer console:

[image: developer consolde]

no second request made. Also I was running a ping during the comment and there was no drop during this comment posting.

Ping results:

```
PING google.com (172.217.10.14): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=51.558 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=45.882 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=41.532 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=40.976 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=61.285 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=49.990 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=52.511 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=65.426 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=53.711 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=56.365 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=59.842 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=40.295 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=12 ttl=56 time=41.938 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=62.801 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=14 ttl=56 time=45.708 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=52.048 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=40.067 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=48.494 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=46.670 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=47.412 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=39.616 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=36.073 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=57.909 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=23 ttl=56 time=41.996 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=24 ttl=56 time=38.335 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=25 ttl=56 time=42.854 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=26 ttl=56 time=44.209 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=27 ttl=56 time=64.938 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=28 ttl=56 time=47.034 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=29 ttl=56 time=45.274 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=30 ttl=56 time=43.272 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=31 ttl=56 time=48.728 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=32 ttl=56 time=48.056 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=33 ttl=56 time=52.748 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=34 ttl=56 time=41.248 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=35 ttl=56 time=39.250 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=36 ttl=56 time=48.956 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=37 ttl=56 time=37.204 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=38 ttl=56 time=55.130 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=39 ttl=56 time=41.921 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=40 ttl=56 time=38.433 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=41 ttl=56 time=56.692 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.10.14: icmp_seq=42 ttl=56 time=45.742 ms
```

Additional note, this seems to only occur on the weekend (saturday/sunday).

Comment: Are you sure you haven't clicked "post" twice? Or reloaded the page and clicked "ok" when the browser asked to resend the form?

Comment: Yes, certain. It has happened four times, this being the fourth. The first I ignored it, second time I thought maybe I had hit it twice, third I knew something was up but deleted the dup so figured it wouldnt be as useful for a ticket. This is over the course of 1-2 weeks. I use DSL (at home) so I think my behavior would not be what most users experience. I also expect the lag so am used to waiting.

Comment: Can one of the Stack Exchange engineers please look into this for chris and post here once they have an answer.

Comment: also happens with chat

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Is there a thread already about that, or is the general practice just to delete the dup?

Comment: Please delete one of the comments when it happens, there's no point leaving both around. SE developers who will come to fix this can see the deleted comments, so it won't affect the chance to fix.

Comment: Thanks, updated question and deleted dup, I'll append ids as I encounter them.

Comment: Explanation on downvote? All I've provided is more details so it can be examined further...